# can't find library after updating Ubuntu [Ogre]

Tags: updates, shared-library

i'm working with ogre for a personnal project.

Yesterday i have updated Ubuntu to the last version with "do-release-upgrade"

the problem is that i was working with ogre on a project, since i have done the update , i have the following message (after successful compilation).

> [ERROR] In function Loader Object Constructor:
>   libboost_thread.so.1.49.0: cannot open shared object file: No such
>   file or directory.

my current version of libboost is 1.54, before i had 1.53 and 1.49 (both) 
DO i have to recompile Ogre ? 
Or do i have to reinstall an older version of libbboost ? ( i have tried this, but can't find how to figure it out)

[Update] : if i cp 'libboost_thread.so.1.54.0' into 'libboost_thread.so.1.49.0'
it launch my programm but SIGSEGV. So could i find the libboost_thread.so.1.49.0

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is Ogre not in the repos? I see a `libogre-1.8.0` and a `libogre-1.9.0` which both depend on Boost, but I'm not sure if these are the same Ogre you're talking about.

Comment: yes its the same ogre

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Ubuntu 14.04, there are two versions of Boost: 1.54.0 and 1.53.0. 1.49.0 is not available.

Instead, you can install Ogre from the main repos (either `libogre-1.8-dev` or `libogre-1.9-dev`, depending on which version you want to develop on). This will ensure that when you upgrade to a new version of Ubuntu, the libraries that you use will be linked against the same version of libraries that are in the main repo. You'll only have to recompile *your* application.

Comment: @Gabson: You do realize that no part of my answer said to recompile Ogre, and that you didn't have to recompile Ogre, right?

Comment: Hum, in fact, before that ubuntu update i had already installed ogre from the main repos (1.8-dev). And it didn't linked the libraries ( instead it erased 1.49 and 1.53) and installed 1.54 (libboost)

Comment: Sounds about right. ogre in Precise(?) was likely linked to Boost 1.49 (since, if I recall correctly, that was the default Boost version). In Trusty, it's linked to Boost 1.54, which is the default Boost version. Unless something is messed up in your `/etc/apt/sources.list` or you have something in `/usr/local/lib`, I'm surprised you got the linker error.